# Code to send print jobs through Jetdirect port

Tags: go, tcp

I have a program made in Go that lets me send files directly to printers through the Jetdirect port. The program works without issue and I can print in any printer with the port 9100 enabled.

```
import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    srcFile := "/path/to/file.pdf"
    serverAddr := "(printerIP):9100"
    uploadFile(srcFile, serverAddr)
}

func uploadFile(srcFile, serverAddr string) {
    // connect to server
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", serverAddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Dial() err: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    // open file to upload
    fi, err := os.Open(srcFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Open() err: %v", err)
    }
    defer fi.Close()
    // upload
    _, err = io.Copy(conn, fi)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Copy() err: %v", err)
    }
}
```

However, I have no control of the process (files are printed as is). I want to be able to customize the print job (choose to print in color or B/W, how many pages per sheet, etc.) but I'm not sure about how to proceed on that, if it's possible. I thought about sending PJL commands and looking for a way to convert the file to Postscript from Go or to apply the changes manually through OpenCV and/or gopdf, save them in a temporal pdf and send that to the Jetdirect port.

Which would be the more viable approach? Or if there is another option, What better way there is to achieve the level of control over print jobs that I need?